# Open a source code in Different Editor based on your Modifier Key

Tags: windows, notepad++, text-editors, gvim, source-code

I use multiple source code editors for my development, namely GVim, Notepad++ and Sublime Text (in that order). (I can consolidate it to one editor, but that is a different discussion). Current setup works well for me with GVim being my main editor, and intermittent use of NPP and ST2.

Is it possible to open a source code file based upon a **modifier key + Enter** key press.? Let me explain.

```
; Default
  `Enter` - Opens the file in Notepad++ (my other team members uses it. So set as a default)

; Vim
  shift + Enter - Open in GVim

; ST2
  Alt + Enter - Open in Sublime Text
```

I am aware that I can add all these in my `right click menu`, as `Open With ...`. But I am looking for even simpler method.

Is it even possible? Any work around are appreciated. Thanks.

*I am using Windows OS.*

Comment: looks like you can probably write an AHK script to do that: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/60723-can-autohotkey-retrieve-file-path-of-the-selected-file/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you use extended File manager. E.g. Total Commander; Double Commander. They have settings for keys, and can setup, than Alt+Enter will do this or this. E.g. run an editor.

From Win Explorer not possible seems.